# Проблема с импортом моделей в юнити 2019

Tags: unity3d

возникла проблема при переноси проекта в новую версию Unity. Все модели потеряли привязку к своим текстурам. А при добавлении новой, текстура не привязывается, хотя раньше все работало. Единственный способ, который я нашел это перетаскивать текстуру в объекты на сцене. С чем это может быть связано?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]